# Convolution of two multivariate guassian distribution for the posterior predictive distribution

Tags: bayesian, posterior, multivariate-normal-distribution, convolution, gibbs

To find the full conditional distribution of $\eta$ for a Gibbs sampling algorithm , I have to show that
$$
p(\eta|-) \propto \int N(\eta;\Omega(\Lambda+\Delta^{-1}\mu),\Omega) N(\mu;\hat{\mu},\Delta/\kappa)d\mu \\= N(\eta; \Omega(\Lambda+\Delta\hat{\mu}), \Omega + \Omega(\kappa\Delta)^{-1}\Omega). 
$$
I know that the integral is similar to the posterior predictive distribution, and maybe I have to manipulate the formula to have something like
$$
\int N(\eta;\Omega(\Lambda+\Delta^{-1}\mu),\Omega) N(\Omega(\Lambda+\Delta^{-1}\mu);\Omega(\Lambda+\Delta^{-1}\hat\mu),\Omega(\kappa\Delta)^{-1}\Omega)d\mu
$$
to apply the rule in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior. How can I show that?

Comment: Using the formula for the multivariate Normal density, expand the quadratic forms in both exponentials, isolate the terms of the form $\mu^\top A \mu$ and $\mu^\top B b$, reconstitute a complete quadratic form, et voilà.

Answer (score 0):

The result easily derives by noticing that
$$
N(\mu;\hat\mu,\Delta/\kappa) \propto N(\Omega(\Lambda + \Delta^{-1}\mu);\Omega(\Lambda + \Delta^{-1}\hat\mu), \Omega(\kappa\Delta)^{-1}\Omega)
$$
since we have that:
$$
(\Omega(\Lambda + \Delta^{-1}\mu) - \Omega(\Lambda + \Delta^{-1}\hat\mu))^T(\Omega(\kappa\Delta)^{-1}\Omega)^{-1}(\Omega(\Lambda + \Delta^{-1}\mu) - \Omega(\Lambda + \Delta^{-1}\hat\mu)) = \\
= (\mu - \hat\mu)^T \Delta^{-1}\Omega(\Omega(\kappa\Delta)^{-1}\Omega)^{-1}\Omega\Delta^{-1}(\mu - \hat\mu) = \\
= (\mu - \hat\mu)^T(\Delta/\kappa)^{-1}(\mu-\hat\mu)
$$